# Create Dynamic Tasks based on Airflow DAG Params or Configs

Tags: airflow

I have a requirement, where I have to create dynamic tasks based on configs passed while `Trigger with Config` option in Airflow.
Context is that, we have a backfilling requirement and Im trying to setup a DAG, that triggers the target dag for different `year` as parameter as an example

Eg if my passed config is `start_year` == `2018`, it should dynamically create the TriggerDAGRunOperators for year > 2018 and chain them

`start`-->`Target_DAG_2018`--> `Target_DAG_2019`-->`Target_DAG_2020`-->`Target_DAG_2021`-->`end`

What would be the best approach to achieve this